# how to split based on space instead of new line?

Tags: python

I have the following code which removes the "refs/changes/digit" but am not getting the expected output,i have the curent output as shown below,can anyone provide inputs on 
how to fix this?

```
source="refs/changes/44/1025744/3 refs/changes/62/1025962/5 refs/changes/45/913745/2"
output = ' '.join(line.split('/', 3)[-1] for line in source.splitlines())
print output


CURRENT OUTPUT:-

1025744/3 refs/changes/62/1025962/5 refs/changes/45/913745/2

expected output

1025744/3 1025962/5 913745/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split on whitespace then split on the first three `"/"` and extract the last element.

```
source="refs/changes/44/1025744/3 refs/changes/62/1025962/5 refs/changes/45/913745/2"
print(" ".join([ele.split("/",3)[-1] for ele in source.split()]))
1025744/3 1025962/5 913745/2
```

some timings:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: timeit " ".join([ele.split("/",3)[-1] for ele in source.split()])
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 µs per loop

In [5]: timeit p.findall(source)

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.84 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use regular expression:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\d{6,7}/\d{1})')
source="refs/changes/44/1025744/3 refs/changes/62/1025962/5 refs/changes/45/913745/2"
print p.findall(source)
```

Note that I explicitly define number before slash to be 6 or 7 characters long (you can adjust regexp to your needs).

Comment: Turns out it's not. I was expecting regexp to be faster, though I don't know how would exactly is Python optimizing your solution.

Comment: re always has a lot of overhead, anything that can be done using split. join etc.. is usually more efficient